# Effect of heteroskedasticity in hierarchical (non-)linear models

Tags: maximum-likelihood, nonlinear-regression, heteroscedasticity, hierarchical-bayesian, consistency

Unlike linear models estimated via OLS where heteroskedasticity lead to inconsistency of the variance estimator but not the coefficient estimates, heteroskedasticity causes inconsistency of both variance and coefficient estimators for the typical non-linear model estimated via maximum likelihood. While adjustments (i.e. "heteroskedastic robust errors") can recover consistent estimation of variances in both cases, it is well known that these corrections are NOT guaranteed to induce consistency of the coefficient MLE estimates for the non-linear case.

While I understand this, could someone explain if/why MLE estimation of non-linear hierarchical model coefficients is consistent in the presence of heteroskedastic errors? My understanding is that getting the error distribution wrong (even if the sampling distribution is guaranteed to be asymptotically normal) and thereby having heteroskedastic error should be particularly problematic in the case of a hierarchical model.